# Xcode Error: Value of type 'int' has no member 'Type' / but what member should I use in that situation?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, appkit, nsalert

what member should I use in that situation?

```
let alertController = NSAlert(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: NSAlertFirstButtonReturn.Type)
```

the whole block:

```
if localSearchResponse == nil{
                    let alertController = NSAlert(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: NSAlertFirstButtonReturn.Type)
                    alertController.addAction(NSAlertDelegate(title: "Dismiss", style: NSAlertStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
```

Comment: NSAlert doesn't have such initializer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433487/create-an-nsalert-with-swift/29433631#29433631. Probably you're thinking of UIAlertController instead, which *does* have such an initializer.

Comment: `NSAlert` does not have an initializer `NSAlert(title:message:preferredStyle:)` . It seems you're mixing up a few classes.