# How do I write an NSAlert in latest swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsalert, macos-sierra

I'm trying to write this alert:

```
func alertUser() {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "message 1"
        alert.informativeText = "info1"
        alert.informativeText = "info2"
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "NO")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "YES")
        alert.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!) { (returnCode: NSModalResponse) -> Void in
            print ("returnCode: ", returnCode)
        }
```

but I get the dreaded `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` message on the line `alert.beginSheetModal`

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest checking to see if `self.view.window` was `nil`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433487/create-an-nsalert-with-swift

Comment: Thanks Eric, but I'm looking for a panel sheet. Does your question resolve that?

Comment: @Rob, what should I do if it is empty?

Comment: @EricAya, thanks for bearing with me.. I want an NSAlert that is attached to the main window.

Comment: @Rob, it is empty

Comment: I solved it by moving the call to the alert to viewDidAppear. Thanks for all the pointers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run your code from `viewDidAppear` because your view controller has not created a window object in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    alertUser()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is the solution!